# Is it possible to do live css changes on a HTML page via python?

Tags: python, html, css

I'm pretty new to Python and not sure, where to start searching. For a small project I'm trying to figure out if one can manipulate CSS code via python, so that dynamic changes are visible in a browser without refreshing the page? Say you want to change the background of some DIV from green to red depending on a recurring python expression/events after the page has been loaded, like a status indicator that changes over time.

Update: The project is a simple network scanner. As pings have to be handled asynchronous, I have to find a way to update the online status of a host in a table after the page has been loaded. It's a HTML page hosted on my Mac, which I open in a tool, which displays it as a dektop wallpaper.

Comment: What are you using? What's your app stack. Because it's different for everything. From the sounds of it you could probably do that with some simple HTTP calls once in awhile.

Comment: I'm using live server on vscode, I don't have any python, but when I save a css stylesheet it automatically updates the page with the new styles without a refresh. Maybe this is useful for you too.
Your question is pretty vague though, no idea what webpage youre trying to manipulate, whether its your own or just a random site.

Comment: What is the webpage you are changing? Is this a .html file on your computer? or is it a webpage on the internet? Where do you expect the python code to run? On your own machine or on a server?

Comment: Just added some details to hopefuly clarify.

Comment: A quick and dirty way is to add a meta refresh tag to your HTML head, to refresh the entire page every (say) 10 seconds: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Examples`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer? Sort of.

What you see in a browser is some application (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), parsing an html file that may contain various text, tags, js, css, etc...and making the determination of how to render that content.  In order for the content to update/change, the html must either re-load or have some javascript  running that directly changes the Document Object Model (DOM). But currently,  there is no mechanism for running python inside of a web page.

Now, that being said, what you *could* do is have some Javascript that listened or polled a *server* written in Python that emitted content/messages/events that your JS framework (in the webpage) responded to and would make the appropriate changes in your DOM. It's not uncommon and that's how a lot of web pages do what they do: Some 'Backend', could be Python or C# or even JS, that responds to requests from a 'Frontend' e.g. your webpage or browser, and sends content, sometimes as JSON instead of HTML.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Yes, these things also came to my mind. JS to manipulate DOM with regularly fired timers. But what will JS pick up? Any sort of stream or file or socket?

Comment: "Any sort of stream or file or socket."

Yea, basically. The specifics can be left as an exercise for the user, but, as an example, using the `fetch` API, you could have a timer periodically make a call to some url that returns some JSON that's then parsed by your webpage for some new content that's then added/used by the page.  For a few Python based servers that are easy to play with, look into Flask, FastAPI, or Pyramid. There's even a `websockets` lib for python if you want to roll your own that could allow you to 'push' updates to the page.

Comment: I ended up by writing everything in Python using `domonic`, writing the HTML to `/tmp` and reloading the page via JS. No JSON at all. So your answer is the one, which helped me most. Thanks.

Comment: Right on! Glad you got something going!